# Multiply object and place at vertices with specific orientation

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, transforms

I have this object: [image: object]

And these vertices connected at their center: [image: vertices]

I want to multiply the object and place mutiples of it at the center of the different vertices, and have all the multiples oriented with their Z-axis away from the center vertex; like so: [image: partial result]

How would I go about doing this?

In the third image, the result is not perfect and the local Z-axis of the object is not aligned well.

Comment: The standard duplication feature for vertices supports rotation, but it wob't align the cone-like meshes like in your example. Personally, I would write a Python script, that calculated the vectors from the central vertex, duplicated the cone-like objects and constructed a transformation matrix for them based on the calculated vector. But someone else may know an easier way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use *[Dupliverts](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliVerts)* to add one copy of the object to each vertex, and then use a *[Constraint](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Tracking/Track_To)* to orient them correctly.

1. Parent the rounded cylinder object to the vertex object by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>:

   [image]
2. Enable *Dupliverts* in *Properties > Object > Duplication* with the vertex object selected and scale the rounded cylinder object down (<kbd>S</kbd>):

   [image]
3. Select the rounded cylinder object and snap the *3D cursor* to it with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>:

   [image]
4. Add an empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Empty > Plain Axes*), it should appear at the center of the rounded cylinder object (where the 3D cursor is). Then select the vertex object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to make the dupliface objects real:

   [image]
5. With one of the rounded cylinder objects selected, add a *Track To* constraint in *Properties > Constraints* and tweak the axes settings:

   [image]
6. With the same rounded cylinder object selected, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Object Data* to select all the other rounded cylinder objects, then copy the constraints by pressing *3D View > Header > Object > Constraints > Copy Constraints to Selected Objects*:

   [image]

If you then snap the vertex object to the 3D cursor, and then delete the two center rounded cylinder objects, you get this:

[image]

## Removing the constraints

To "apply" the constraints to the object transforms, select all the rounded cylinder objects again:

1. Select one of them and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Object Data*
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Apply Visual Transform* make their actual rotation the same as the constrained rotation.

Then remove the constraints:

1. Remove the constraint from one by pressing the X on the constraint in *Properties > Constraints*.
2. Copy it to the others with *3D View > Header > Object > Constraints > Copy Constraints to Selected Objects*.

Comment: Should the cylinders follow the verts when you rotate the verts object? Is that possible? As parenting them messes up the position.

Comment: @Neil Even after removing the constraints? Try parenting with *Keep Transform*.

Comment: I went thought it again and it worked fine, I must have missed something. Great explanations you give in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to recreate the same setup using Sverchok nodes:
[image]

The placement of instance and also rotation angle of each bullet is the interesting parts.DupliVerts and orientation that is dependant of the parent might be sufficient.

But nodes might give more control of the whole thing.

[image]

VIDEO:
https://youtu.be/MYoq4kUbakg